# Codeigniter Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo esto

```
$route['categoria/(:any)'] = 'site/categorias/$1';
$route['subcategoria/(:any)'] = 'site/subcategorias/$1';
```

Los puedo cambiar a esto ?

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/categorias/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/subcategorias/$1';
```

Quiero que todas las urls salgan desde el root.

Comment: translate your question, this is the spanish version of SO please @Ramirto Jaramillo

Comment: No, no vas a poder, va a querer entrar al primer match.

Comment: porque mejor no usas funciones? como `$route['(.+)'] = function ($params){$param = explode('/', $params);  if( in_array($param[0], array('categorias', 'subcategorias'))){return 'site/' . $parmas;} }`

Comment: Gracias, consulta, eso lo tengo que poner en el controlador ? Yo lo que quiero es que todo el sitio sea algo como base_url()/viajes o base_url()/amazon o base_url()/walmart. En el archivo routes como tendría que quedar ? O eso va el el archivo route  ?

Comment: depende de que represente `/viajes` , `/amazon`,  `/walmart` son 3 paginas diferentes? se pueden poner mas cosas que esas? que pasa si uno pone `/cucurucho` que muestra? arma la página a partir de la palabra, o daría error?

Comment: Ah ok, te cuento, yo arme un controlador que se llama site($slug) de ahi salen funciones una categorias otra funcion subcategoria y otra funcion tiendas. Yo estaba armando el sitio para que las urls sean categoria/deportes subcategoria/tenis tienda/netshoes por ejemplo pero quiero que todo salga del base_url ej mistio.com/deportes o misitio.copm/netshoes pero no logro hacerlo. Categorias, subcategorias y tiendas estan en tablas distintas en la base de datos